# Bimolecular and Isomerization reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, biophysics, biology

Is it possible to describe a reaction of the

$$ A+B \rightleftharpoons AB $$
exactly using the solution of an isomerization reaction?
$$A \rightleftharpoons B$$

I just can not figure it out the equations seem so similar but the solution in my script is so convoluted that I can not prove they are equal.

Equations for top reaction:
$${\partial c_{AB} \over \partial t} = -k_{off} c_{AB} + k_{on} c_A c_B$$

and for the bottom:
$${\partial c_{A} \over \partial t} = -k_{A\rightarrow B} c_{A} + k_{B \rightarrow A} c_B $$
$${\partial c_{B} \over \partial t} = k_{A\rightarrow B} c_{A} - k_{B \rightarrow A} c_B $$

could we not just represent $ A+B \rightleftharpoons AB $ as a new reaction with $C = A+B$ and $D = AB$ and thus use the isomerization results on $C \rightleftharpoons D$?

---

A starting point might to prove they can be used to express eachother would be to use the equilibrium relation $k_d = { c_A c_B \over c_{AB}}$ with the relation for the total number of species A $ c^{total} = c_A + c_{AB}$ to get :
$$c_A c_B = k_d (c^t -c_A)$$

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?